# Error when trying to select event data with BigQuery

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to select the `event_dim.date` within BigQuery but am unable to actually access it due to an error

```
Error: Cannot access field date on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<date STRING, name STRING, params ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT, ...>>>, ...>> at [1:18]
```

My Query:

```
SELECT event_dim.date FROM `table`
```

I know I'm doing something wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to get an array of the dates for each row? Then you want an ARRAY subquery:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT date FROM UNNEST(event_dim)) AS dates
FROM `table`;
```

If you are trying to get all dates in separate rows, then you want to cross join with the array:

```
SELECT event.date
FROM `table`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event;
```

To filter for a particular date:

```
SELECT event.date
FROM `table`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE event.date = '20170104';
```

Or you can parse the date string as a `date` type, which would let you filter on the year or week, for example:

```
SELECT date
FROM (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event.date) AS date
  FROM `table`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
)
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = 2017;
```

Comment: How would I use `date` within my queries, for example a `where` clause.

Comment: I updated my answer now; see if these other examples help.